# Handling FormView databinding event on MasterPage from ContentPage

Tags: master-pages, interaction

Hoping this is simple.  My goal is to have my masterpage carry a formview which can bind data retrieved based on variable held in my content page, or in the alternative based on variable held as a session variable.  As a test, I set up a masterpage including a formview id=testerFV. There is also a label on page `id=receiveno`.  From the masterpage I made a public property:

```
Public ReadOnly Property testerFVx() As FormView

    Get
        Return Me.testerFV
    End Get
End Property
```

Similarly, a public property for the receiveno label.

I added `<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/masterpages/testmaster.master" %>` to my content page.  On my content page, I included a button titled testit.  Backcode for the testit button is this:

```
Protected Sub testit_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles testit.Click

    Dim tester1FVx As FormView = Master.testerFVx

    If tester1FVx IsNot Nothing Then
        Master.receivenox.Text = "testerfvx is not nothing"
    Else
        Master.receivenox.Text = "testerfvx is nothing"
    End If

End Sub
```

The label displays "testerfvx is nothing" so apparently the receiveno label is findable in the masterpage through the public property, but I'm not finding the formview.

In another quick test, I tried binding the formview on the masterpage on the page load with a dummy collection like this:

```
 Protected Sub page_load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim thisthing As New List(Of fakenumbers)
    Dim thisone As New fakenumbers
    thisone.Thisnumber = 42
    thisthing.Add(thisone)

    testerFV.DataSource = thisthing
    testerFV.DataBind()

End Sub
```

But I get an object not found error.

So:  bottom line, how do I access a formview located on a masterpage from an event happening on my content page and using variables currently held on the content page.  Also, if I include a `testerFV_databound` handler in the master page, will it respond correctly when I've triggered the databinding event from my content page?

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!